# Can't find controller in Spring annotation for AJAX

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-annotations

I tried to load data via AJAX in Spring 3.0, but the AJAX URL can't find the controller in Spring, and I don't know how to fix this.

I know while server start it looks up the URL and gets data but here I can't crate annotation properly in spring and I have searched the web a lot but have not succeeded.

My Java class:

```
package springactiontest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import Dao.dao;


@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class mainclass {

    @RequestMapping(value="/AddUser",method=RequestMethod.GET)

public @ResponseBody static String data(ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {

        System.err.println("err ocured");

          ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

          setvalueclass studentJDBCTemplate =(setvalueclass)context.getBean("actionclass");

          System.out.println("------list district--------" );

        JSONArray newtest=new JSONArray();

          List<dao> students = studentJDBCTemplate.listStudents();
          for (dao record : students) 
          {

             JSONObject ob=new JSONObject();
             System.out.print("ID test: " + record.getDistrict());
             ob.put("distrct", record.getDistrict());
             newtest.add(ob);
          }

          System.err.println("error");


          String res=newtest.toString();

          System.err.println("error"+res);

        return res;

     }

}
Jsp:
$("document").ready(function () {

        alert("distrcict");

        dist_pop();

});

function dist_pop() {

var urlService="http://tamilnilam:8080/SpringTest";
        $.ajax({
        url: urlService +'/AddUser',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',

        contentType: "application/json",
          success: function (data) {

            alert("sucess")          

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

            alert("Error Occured in dist pop");

        }

    });

}
```

applicationcontext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>       
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  

   <context:component-scan base-package="springactiontest.setvalueclass"/>


   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://10.163.2.165:5434/land_rural"/>
      <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
   </bean> 


   <bean id="actionclass" class="springactiontest.setvalueclass">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Are you obtaining a 404 http error?

Comment: Remove that commented code, and please keep the code in line. like no blank space between requestmapping and the method definition. Secondly, what is the error you are getting? How to say whats wrong without error. Thridly, please also paste your servlet-context.xml or similar which you have.

Comment: @ fran Montero yes 404 am getting error

Comment: @user3607180 Can you share your bean definition file?

Comment: @WeareBorg while i click browser console  i am getting 404 error

Comment: Ya, Bean definition file, I couldnt figure out the word... thanks karna.. :D

Comment: Look over context path

Comment: One thing I noticed is that your javascript code is expecting  JSONP. What happens when you just go to http://tamilnilam:8080/SpringTest/AddUser in the browser? Is your web.xml properly configured?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question a little. I improved the spelling, and I also Improved the title of your question to make it more findable. In the future, try to use proper spelling so your question is more readable and understandable. I've also added a relevant tag, which will help people find your question.

Comment: k thanks for u r information i will correct

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `component-scan` is missing, it helps Spring to detect and instantiate Spring beans which are annotated with `@Component`, `@Service`,`@Repository`, `@Controller`, `@Endpoint` etc

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.your.controller.package" />

    // Rest of the bean defiantions
</beans>
```

For reference : [Spring MVC tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/)

Comment: where i need to add itbean.xml ?? what is use of it

Comment: after update as u said again 404 error only appear not yet solved

Comment: @user3607180 Can you share updated bean definition file?